# Are there any dialects of English which ⟨i⟩ in unstress syllable will be realized as [ɪ]?

Tags: english, phonology, dialects

The pronunciation of "dilute" should be /daɪˈlut/, but according to Wikipedia, another acceptable pronunciation of this word is /d**ɪ**ˈlut/. So I summarize this rule as "/aɪ/ is realized as [ɪ] if it is in an unstress syllable. I am wondering which dialect accept this rule?

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to the assumptions apparently underlying your question, the variation in pronunciation of words beginning with *di-* (*dilute, direct, dilemma, diverse*, etc.) between /ɪ/ (which may further be reduced to or merged with /ə/) and /aɪ/ is a supraphonemic, not subphonemic, difference. In English, all full vowels can occur in stressed or unstressed syllables, and most speakers are capable of pronouncing these words with either option. The variation is conditioned not by phonetic environment but lexically, so it cannot be expressed in a phonological rule that's supposed to always apply in the given context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any evidence that "dilute" *should* be [daɪˈlut] in English, but some people do pronounce it that way. So we can inquire into why there is variation in pronunciation. It does have to do with stress, and also the ambiguity of English orthography. Finally, w.r.t. [ɪ] specifically, it has to do with phonetic quality of schwa as influenced by surrounding consonants. Initial-reduced pronunciations of "dilute" vary continuously between [dəˊlut] and [dɪˊlut]. In many dialects of English, there is a tongue fronting-and-raising tendency in schwa between coronal consonants, and to a lesser extent just after. You would want to engage in a controlled quantitative study of a specific lect to get a more precise characterization of the physical output of the reduced vowel.

Pretonic initial vowels in English are somewhat ambiguous in orthography, in that there is a distinction between "long" and "short" vowels in the language, but that is only imperfectly encoded in spelling. Therefore and especially for less-common words, people have to guess whether the vowel is treated (by others in their community) as long or as short. This gives rise to alternative pronunciations like [i ~ ɛ]conomic, [i ~ ɛ]conomy.

Words like "dilute" are characterized by having a single syllable immediately before the main stress. Given the nature of English stress rhythm, this is a bit distressing, because we have an orphaned syllable that is not part of a stress foot. It's not impossible to have an initial unstressed monosyllabic span – a "degenerate foot" – but speakers tend to do something about it. A common strategy is to completely reduce a short syllable to a prosodic stub (something appended above the level of the prosodic word). This accounts for the vowel alternation in "syllable ~ syllabic" where when unstressed the short [ɪ] attested in "syllable" becomes schwa in "syllabic", though in physical production due to consonantal influence the vowel may sometimes be pronounced with [ɪ].

Orthographic "ll" is a strong indicator that <y> in this root is a short vowel, and when stressed it is never [aɪ]. Single  <i> before a single consonant is ambiguous as to being long vs. short, therefore "pileated" (which has main stress on the initial vowel) is pronounced variably with [ɪ] or [aɪ]. "Dilute" is similar in that there aren't strong orthographic indicators that the vowel is long vs. short. Speakers are free to treat the initial vowel as long or as short, but also because that syllable is immediately pre-stressed, it can be shortened even if it is treated as long, which further contributes to the occurrence of a reduced initial vowel.

Your generalization goes in the right direction, and just needs some amending as to when and why this happens. As for the "which dialect" question, this is not governed by geographical dialect, it is more a social marker. I don't know of any sociolinguistic studies that try to discern an underlying attitudinal cause for vowel shortening vs. retention in this context, but I suspect that slow speech tilts the scale in favor of [aɪ], in that if you pronounce the word very slowly, you are more likely to produce [aɪ] (which is even the name of the letter), and many people are concerned with "not slurring their speech".

Comment: Kenyon and Knott's (1950) [_Pronouncing dictionary of American English_](https://archive.org/details/pronouncingdicti00unse/page/n5/mode/2up?view=theater) famously uses [ɪ] instead of [i] for words spelled with final Y, like _pretty, handy, easy,_ etc. It sounds strange to me, but they say lots of Americans talked like that in 1950.

Comment: @jlawler The same thing happens/ed in RP (SSBE). This led John Wells to invent the < i > notation for RP, where it stood for a vowel which might be /i:/ for some speakers or /ɪ/ for others. I had always been under the impression that /ɪ/ was dying and virtually obsolete in those environments in RP. However, I'm observing a steady stream of young RP speakers with /ɪ/ there. Anyhow, JW, aware of the confusion this notation caused ("Is /i/ a distinct phoneme?" etc) later remarked '*It seemed like a good idea at the time*'!